# Mal rendimiento con 5 select donde uno depende del otro en Angular 11 y RxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs

Estoy haciendo una aplicación web en Angular 11.

Tengo una pantalla llamada "Mi Perfil", donde puedes completar tu dirección residencial seleccionando opciones de 5 select/dropdowns.

1. Provincia
2. Municipio
3. Sección
4. Sector
5. Calle

Uno depende del otro, es decir, debo seleccionar primero Provincia y hacer un HTTP request para obtener los Municipios. Luego de seleccionar el Municipio, debo hacer otro HTTP request para obtener las Secciones, y así sucesivamente.

**Problema:**
Presento un mal rendimiento luego de 3-5 segundos en la pantalla. Si quisiera moverme a otra pantalla haciendo click en otro menú, la página se friza y no reacciona. Es como si algo se quedara colgado o anda consumiendo muchos recursos y no son liberados.

**Componente**

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './billing-address-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./billing-address-form.component.scss']
})
export class BillingAddressFormComponent extends AutoUnsubscribeComponent implements OnInit {
  
  // Dropdowns, primero obtengo todas las provincias el cual es el primer select.
  provinces$: Observable<ICommonDropdown[]> = this.profileService.fetchProvinces();
  boroughs$: Observable<ICommonDropdown[]>;
  sections$: Observable<ICommonDropdown[]>;
  sectors$: Observable<ICommonDropdown[]>;
  streets$: Observable<ICommonDropdown[]>;

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private profileService: ProfileService,
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initForm();
    this.onFormValueChanges();
    this.fetchMyBillingAddress();
  }

  get f(): { [key: string]: AbstractControl } {
    return this.form.controls;
  }

  initForm(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      // Dropdowns
      provinceId: [null, Validators.required],
      boroughId: [null, Validators.required],
      sectionId: [null, Validators.required],
      sectorId: [null, Validators.required],
      streetId: [null, Validators.required],
      // Otros campos normales de tipo input
      number: [null],
      aptNo: [null],
      building: [null],
      kilometer: [null],
      square: [null],
      peaton: [null],
      reference: [null]
    });
  }

  /**
   * Primer paso.
   * Obtener mi dirección actual para llenar el formulario.
   * La función "addSubscriptions" proviene de la clase que extiendo el cual se encarga de
   * guardar las subscripciones y eliminarlas cuando el componente es destruido.
   */
  fetchMyBillingAddress(): void {
    this.addSubscriptions(
      this.profileService.fetchMyBillingAddress()
        .subscribe(res => this.form.patchValue(res)) // <- Entro valores a mi FormGroup.
    );
  }

  /**
   * Segundo paso.
   * Notar el operador "distinctUntilChanged", solo me interesa reaccionar a cambios de los dropdowns.
   * Si alguno cambia, realizo el HTTP request correspondiente.
   */
  onFormValueChanges(): void {
    this.addSubscriptions(
      this.form.valueChanges
        .pipe(
          // Solo ejecuta si los valores de los dropdowns del estado pasado y el estado actual son diferentes.
          // Evita realizar múltiples llamdas HTTP innecesarias.
          distinctUntilChanged((a, b) => {
            // Clono los estados para evitar manipular directamente mi FormGroup.
            const stateA = LodashUtil.cloneDeep(a);
            const stateB = LodashUtil.cloneDeep(b);
            // Nombres de los demás FormControls que no me interesa, por tanto, los elimino de ambos estados.
            const propsToDelete = [
              'number', 'aptNo', 'building', 'kilometer',
              'square', 'peaton', 'reference', 'streetId'
            ];
            propsToDelete.forEach(prop => {
              delete stateA[prop];
              delete stateB[prop];
            });
            const changeA = JSON.stringify(stateA);
            const changeB = JSON.stringify(stateB);
            return changeA === changeB;
          })
        )
        .subscribe(values => {
          const provinceId = values.provinceId;
          const boroughId = values.boroughId;
          const sectionId = values.sectionId;
          const sectorId = values.sectorId;
          
          // Realizo las llamadas HTTP si alguno de los dropdowns ha cambiado.
          if (boroughId) {
            this.boroughs$ = this.profileService.fetchBoroughs(provinceId);
          }
          if (sectionId) {
            this.sections$ = this.profileService.fetchSections(provinceId, boroughId);
          }
          if (sectorId) {
            this.sectors$ = this.profileService.fetchSectors(provinceId, boroughId, sectionId);
            this.streets$ = this.profileService.fetchStreets(provinceId, boroughId, sectionId, sectorId);
          }
        })
    );
  }

}
```

**Template**

Aquí utilizo un componente re-utilizable para pintar los select. A continuación solo muestro cómo le paso el arreglo a cada uno para evitar que el código se alargue y se entienda mejor.

Al final, el componente re-utilizable es un [select de Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/forms/#form-controls).

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

  <!-- Province -->
  <app-select-form-control formControlName="provinceId"
                           label="Provincia"
                           [items]="provinces$ | async">
  </app-select-form-control>

  <!-- Borough -->
  <app-select-form-control formControlName="boroughId"
                           label="Municipio"
                           [items]="boroughs$ | async">
  </app-select-form-control>

  <!-- Section -->
  <app-select-form-control formControlName="sectionId"
                           label="Sección"
                           [items]="sections$ | async">
  </app-select-form-control>

  <!-- Sector -->
  <app-select-form-control formControlName="sectorId"
                           label="Sector"
                           [items]="sectors$ | async">
  </app-select-form-control>

  <!-- Street -->
  <app-select-form-control formControlName="streetId"
                           label="Calle"
                           [items]="streets$ | async">
  </app-select-form-control>

  <!-- Number -->
  <app-input-form-control formControlName="number"
                          label="Número">
  </app-input-form-control>

  <!-- Apartment -->
  <app-input-form-control formControlName="aptNo"
                          label="Apartamento">
  </app-input-form-control>

  <!-- Building -->
  <app-input-form-control formControlName="building"
                          label="Edificio">
  </app-input-form-control>

  <!-- Kilometer -->
  <app-input-form-control formControlName="kilometer"
                          label="Kilómetro">
  </app-input-form-control>

  <!-- Square -->
  <app-input-form-control formControlName="square"
                          label="Manzana">
  </app-input-form-control>

  <!-- Peaton -->
  <app-input-form-control formControlName="peaton"
                          label="Peatón">
  </app-input-form-control>

  <!-- Reference -->
  <app-input-form-control formControlName="reference"
                          label="Referencia">
  </app-input-form-control>

</form>
```

No estoy seguro qué está causando la ralentización en mi código y por más que busco, no encuentro una falla.

Mi objetivo es determinar qué está causando la lentitud que presento al entrar en la pantalla y conseguir un buen rendimiento al usar tantos select donde uno depende del otro.

Comment: yo creo que lo puedes enfocar desde otro punto de vista. Estoy seguro que el problema de rendimiento está en el deepclone que haces. Imagina que por cada select tienes 100 valores(5*100=500) objetos(mínimos) a clonar. Encima esto se hace por cada cambio en el form. Deberías escuchar el evento `change` en el select que tenga hacer llamada al server y no los cambios de todo el form. Puedes ocultar los selects que dependen uno del otro. En funcion de que vaya rellenando los selects vas mostrando el siguiente

Comment: @hawks Puede ser, no se me había ocurrido. Probaré utilizando el evento `change` de cada select de manera individual de acuerdo a tu recomendación a ver que tal. Gracias por la observación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo diría que el problema es que el código de `onFormValueChanges()` es demasiado complicado y por eso no encuentras qué está causando el bajo rendimiento. Sin ánimo de ofender, diría que tienes dos problemas: uno es el rendimiento; el otro, un código demasiado complejo que es difícil de depurar. Lo que yo haría sería refactorizar para eliminar ese método y cambiar de enfoque.

1. Implementa el evento `(change)` en `InputFormControlComponent`, un `OutputEmitter` que emita el evento `(change)` del `select`.
2. En `BillingAddressFormComponent` crea métodos para cargar cada uno de los dropdowns, un método por dropdown. Por ejemplo:

```
private populateBoroughs(provinceId) {
  this.boroughs$ = provinceId ? this.profileService.fetchBoroughs(provinceId) : of([]);
}
```

3. En el `(change)` de cada dropdown llama al método para cargar el dropdown dependiente.

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias por la idea. Al final usé el `valueChanges` de cada `FormControl` por separado. Es decir me subscribo al `valueChanges` de cada uno de los `FormControl`s que son para mi dropdowns. Al final, es el mismo comportamiento que propones, o bueno, casi el mismo. Me funciona y no tuve que modificar mi componente re-utilizable.

Comment: Me alegro de que te sirviera. Ha mejorado el rendimiento?

Comment: Por mucho. Ya no tengo picos de consumo de memoria o memory leaks. Se siente fluido la pantalla y todo en orden.